# concatenate files from different subdirectories

Tags: linux, concatenation

I have many subfolders from my current operating directory. In each subfolder, there is a file called "total"

"total" contains 2 columns of data, and remember there are many "total" files, each in the different subfolders.

I have been tirelessly going into each folder, opening each total, and pasting into a spreadsheet. Could I Expedite the process though?

Can I concatenate all files named "total" in all the subfolders into a single file called "total all" in my current folder, which has all the data next to one  another?

In other words the 1st two columns of my new file would be the 2 columns from the first subfolder (in alphabetical order), columns 3 and 4 would be the data from the total file next in line, etc.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`find . -maxdepth 1 -name total | sort | xargs paste`

Comment: Are you sure this only goes into one directory below? It seems to be taking way to long and I am wondering if it is trying to concatenate all files with this name on my computer. Also, I need them to be next to each other. This has 2 columns only with each file pasted below the previous one

Comment: I used mindepth to fix the first issue. But how do i join them horizontally and not vertically?

Comment: I didn't "ding you" whatever that means. And it's not my downvote. It's up to you to take my suggestion on board and improve your answer. By the way the OP doesn't seem very happy with your answer, so that's another reason to improve it.

Comment: @JacksonHart -- I missed the original requirement for columns. Use `paste` instead of `cat`. By default it does tab separation, but you can change that if you want to generate a CSV.

Comment: @BowlesCR What order is it pasting them in? It does not appear to be alphabetical

Comment: Whatever order `find` encounters them (directory order) which is somewhat unpredictable. Adding `sort` to the chain will fix that.

Comment: @BowlesCR Can you add this to the answer?

Comment: Sure thing, answer edited.